# MVC How to get the validation styles for input elements not wired up to the View Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my view I have a search field, `id = searchPrimaryTrade`.
It is a requirement that a primary trade is found and submitted.

I use jquery to copy the id of the selected trade into the hidden field;

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PrimaryTradeId)
```

If the user does not enter a primary trade, an error message is displayed.

However what I also want to do is trigger the same validation css styles to the search text field `(id = searchPrimaryTrade)` and display the `*` marker next to it. 
In other words, I want the text box to be given a red border.

In the code below, this is what happens when the companyName is not entered.
So how do I do this?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ViewContext.FormContext.ValidationSummaryId = "valSumId";
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please fix these errors.", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "valSumId" } });

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create Subcontractor</legend>
        <p class="highlight">@ViewBag.Message</p>
        <table class="formTable">
            <tr>
                <td class="leftCell">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subcontractor.CompanyName) </td>
                <td class="rightCell">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subcontractor.CompanyName, new { @style = "width: 300px;" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subcontractor.CompanyName, "*")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="leftCell">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimaryTrade)</td>
                <td class="rightCell"><input type="search" name="searchPrimaryTrade" id="searchPrimaryTrade" data-scd-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutocompletePrimaryTrade", "DataService")" style = "width: 300px;" data-val="true" data-val-required="Must enter a Primary Trade" class="primaryTrade required"/>
                    <input type="button" id="ResetPrimaryTrade" value="Reset"/><br/>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PrimaryTradeId)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryTradeId, "*")
                    Cannot find the trade? @Html.DialogFormButton("Add New Trade", Url.Action("AddTrade", "Popup"), "Add New Trade", null, Url.Action("Create"), "buttonAddNewTrade")
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: just use `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.searchPrimaryTrade , "*")` below the `searchPrimaryTrade` text field.

Comment: I would have to put searchPrimaryTrade in the model to begin with?

Comment: Yes and you can make it as `[Required]`

Answer (score 4):

You don't really need this hidden field. You could simply decorate the `PrimaryTradeId` property on your view model with the `[Required]` attribute:

```
[Required]
public int? PrimaryTradeId { get; set; }
```

and then use the `Html.TextBoxFor` and `Html.ValidationMessageFor` helpers instead of hardcoding some input fields in your markup:

```
<td class="rightCell">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(
        model => model.PrimaryTradeId,
        new {
            type = "search",
            data_scd_autocomplete = Url.Action("AutocompletePrimaryTrade", "DataService"),
            style = "width: 300px;",
            @class = "primaryTrade required"
        }
    )
    <input type="button" id="ResetPrimaryTrade" value="Reset"/><br/>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryTradeId, "*")

    Cannot find the trade? 
    @Html.DialogFormButton(
        "Add New Trade", 
        Url.Action("AddTrade", "Popup"), 
        "Add New Trade", 
        null, 
        Url.Action("Create"), 
        "buttonAddNewTrade"
    )
</td>
```

The Html helpers will now take care of generating the proper markup and emitting the correct validation attributes based on the data annotations on your model.

Comment: The problem is that the model.PrimaryTradeId is meant to be a number, the integer Id of the trade, and this solution will populate it with text. The user of course wants to see text, but when the form is posted the datatype will be wrong for that field.

Comment: Then you could leave the hidden field and put the `PrimaryTrade` string property on your view model with the `[Required]` attribute. Obviously the ValidationMessageFor helper will be pointing to the visible `PrimaryTrade` property for which you have an input field. Then using javascript you could populate the value of the hidden field when a selection is made from the AutoComplete box.

Comment: Yes I can do that. However what is required is that the PrimaryTradeId  must be > 0 which I populate from javascript and proves that a valid primary trade has been selected.

Comment: But that will be the case because you will always set a value to this hidden field with javascript. And if the user doesn't select anything, the Required validator for the `PrimaryTrade` string field will kick in and display the error message.

Comment: The user might enter some text that is not selected from autocomplete. So for PrimaryTrade the required validator is satisfied, but the PrimaryTradeId is 0 or null which is NOT valid. How do I configure this validation?

Comment: If you subscribe to the `change` event of the input field you could always set the corresponding value of the hidden field.

Comment: You also have the possibility to perform custom validation on the server: if there's a value for the `PrimaryTrade` field but the `PrimaryTradeId` field is empty this would mean that you are in this case and you could act accordingly.

Comment: If the user directly types some text into the input field without using the AutoComplete there will be nothing to set the hidden field value which is a situation you cold detect on your server and fail the validation for the `PrimaryTrade` field.